# How much space there is to use for CACHE MANIFEST downloads? (per web app)

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, webview

Is there a limit to how much data I can download with `CACHE MANIFEST` for offline usage in my `PhoneGap` web app?

Comment: Not an answer but have you read http://www.alistapart.com/articles/application-cache-is-a-douchebag/

Comment: @SimonMacDonald thanks for the link... it's a very informative article!